# Yaml Support for Kubernetes in VSCode

Tags: kubernetes, visual-studio-code

I am trying to use VS code editor for creating kubernetes yaml files, by some reason, vscode is not showing auto-complete commands or space in my yaml files even though I have installed Yaml Support by Redhat extension and configured yaml.schema file as per below:

**{
"yaml.schemas": {
"Kubernetes": "*.yaml"
}
}**

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: I have just installed the yaml extension from readhat and the kubernetes extension. I didnt have to set any schema specifically like you did.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know why your config does not work. Here's mine:

```
{
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Default Light+",
    "workbench.startupEditor": "none",
    "editor.cursorSurroundingLines": 5,
    "window.zoomLevel": 3,
    "redhat.telemetry.enabled": false,
    "yaml.schemas": {
        "Kubernetes": [
            "deploy*.yaml"
        ],
    },
}
```

This snippet works for me which currently selects `deploy*.yaml` files.

I added rest of settings just to show overall structure. Only `yaml.schemas` part matters, of course.

To access this file one should press command+shift+P (macOS), and type `>user settings json` in the search. To reload vscode one should press command+shift+P and then type `>reload window` there.

I tried to match `*.yaml` and it works as well.

Hopefully this answer will help some vscode newbie like me. It's not very obvious how to proceed with yaml configuration after initial install.

Comment: This worked for me with the ms-kubernetes-tools.vscode-kubernetes-tools and redhat.vscode-yaml extensions - +1

Answer (score 3):

[image]**Fix This Problem On The Vscode Step by Step**

**Step 1 :** install yaml plugin on the vscode 
**Step 2 :** Edit this path vscode **file>prefrences>settings>Extention>YAML**
**Step 3 :** After Click Yaml on the right side find and edit  **YAML: Custom Tag Edit in setings.json**
**Step 4 :** Append This lines in File Settings.json

***"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/yannh/kubernetes-json-schema/master/v1.22.4-standalone-strict/all.json": ["/*.yaml","/*.yml"]***

**Step 5 :** Final Reload vscode You can use **Ctrl+Shift+p** and search **Reload Window**  On The Vscode

Answer (score -1):

you can try it.

```
"yaml.schemas": {
    "http://www.schemastore.org/json/composer": ["/*"],
    "kubernetes": ["/*.yaml"]
},
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

try this.

```
{ 
    "yaml.schemas": {

      "Kubernetes": "*.yaml" 
      },
      "redhat.telemetry.enabled": true
    }
```

Comment: It's important to not just post code, but to also include a description of what the code does and why you are suggesting it. This helps others understand the context and purpose of the code, and makes it more useful for others who may be reading the question or answer,  @Amith.